# What do I do with files that were modified during a Nuget Restore in SourceTree?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new to SourceTree and I'm working on a solution in Visual Studio that I checked out of Git. After check-out, naturally, the first thing I did was build the solution. This kicked in the Nuget Restore mechanism which started doing things to some files in the solution. Everything compiled without errors, but when I look in SourceTree I see that a bunch of files were added to the Unstaged Files list. Most of them were `.dll` files, some were `.xml` files, some where even executables like WebGrease (`WG.exe`).

Do I put them all in the ignore list? And if yes, do I commit this `.gitignore` file that also gets added to the Unstaged Files list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you shouldn't put any files in Git that are results of the build. This includes compiled binaries, temporary files, dependencies downloaded through a dependency management tool like npm, Bower or NuGet.

It's perfectly safe to ignore these files - just add them to your `.gitignore` file. Try to use patterns to exclude groups of similar files and directories.

And yes, add the `.gitignore` file to your Git repo, commit it there. This will make sure that other people accessing the same repo will have the same list of ignore patterns.

If there are build results that you need to keep, i.e. a binary release of your product, or a generated installer, then I suggest you copy/upload them to a central storage location as part of your release process. This could be a shared folder, a file server, or another Git repo - but I would not keep them in the same repo as the sources.

BTW: Here's a template `.gitignore` file for use with Visual Studio projects: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Give this a try - it looks like a good starting point.